# Apply slide transition when changing slides only without affecting the overlay blocks

Tags: beamer, transition

When i use a transition, turns out it affects on some overlay blocks as well.

For example, i use itemize (5 items) and put `\transcover` in the frame environment, naturally when i run the document on the pdf reader, the slide transition works perfectly, but the overlay number is affected like happens on each item and i don't want it. Actually it's annoying to wait the transition run on some overlays. I only need the transition effect when the slide is changing, not the overlay.

How to do that? Any help would be appreciated

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{yellow!50!white}{cyan!50!white}

\title{The title of the paper}
\author{Sofyane Bouameur}
\institute{\textbf{ResearchGate}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \transwipe[direction=90]
\frametitle{Summary}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First SubSection}
\begin{frame}
    \transcover
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=red!80!black} %Ganti warna block title
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=red!10!white}  % Ganti warna block body
\begin{block}<1->{Title}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item <2-> {One.}
        \item <3-> {Two.}
        \item <4-> {Three.}
        \item <4-> {Four.}
        \item <5-> {Five.}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\transcover<1>` sems to give what you want.